# Memory increases when upgrade ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.2.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-2.2

I was using Ruby 1.9.3 + Rails 3.2.22 in heroku, recently i have upgraded ruby 1.9.3 to 2.2.10 then i could see that memory is growing fast and getting memory quota, we were using performance L dynos and WEB_CONCURRENCY as 80. Will it help anything with GC Tuning?

Before the upgrade memory was reaching 14gb after 9 PM only
[image]
After the upgrade memory was reaching 14 gb on every 4 hours
[image]

Comment: Do you know which parts of your app. are causing the memory spikes or is it a leak that keeps compounding while idle?

Comment: @bkunzi01 i have updated the topic, thanks

Comment: Finding memory leaks is hard.  I use Valgrind-Massif which is a heap profiler and great for looking at memory consumption but that will only give you half of the puzzle since it won't dive in to your ruby code it will just tell you if it's from object creation etc.  Couple that with Stackprof and you should be able to track it down.  I hear New Relic is great too but haven't used it.